# Javascript ajax synchronous request is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making sequential AJAX requests for my websites. There are 2 POST requests. The second request should be processed after first request is done. My code is as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/backend/edge/enableNewAgent/',
    async: false,
    success: function () {
        console.log("First Process Done");
    }
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/backend/edge/deleteOldAgent/',
    async: false,
    success: function () {
        console.log("Second Process Done");
    }
});
```

The second process is done after first process, but the console logging is executed after second process done, not after first process done. I want the `console.log` is executed soon after first process done, then continue executing the second process. Can someone help ?

Comment: oops, I read "asynchronous" sorry - anything in the developer tools console to show what weird thing may be going on? .... note: you know the first A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous, so `async:false` is kind of an oxymoron :p

Comment: Never use `async: false`. It is the cause of the problem as the thread to update the console is blocked by the second AJAX request, so both items appear at the same time, after both requests have completed. To fix this use the callback pattern properly by making the second AJAX call *within* the `success` handler function of the first.

Comment: In Chrome, at least, console logging is not synchronous.  By using `async: false` you don't yield control back to the event loop so the `console.log` lines get queued up.

Comment: in fact, not console.log, but like changing progressbar length from 10% to 20% @Alnitak

Comment: https://jsbin.com/kovisedoqu/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WilliamsPerdana it's the same thing - DOM display updates get queued up to be processed in one hit during the event loop, but by using `async: false` you never give the browser the chance to update itself between the AJAX calls.

Comment: @Quentin the `console.log` thing is a red herring - the OP in reality is trying to update the DOM between the calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write synchronous "looking" code and avoid synchronous XMLHttpRequest - you can use async/await

```
async function doAjax() {
    await $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/backend/edge/enableNewAgent/',
        success: function() {
            console.log("First Process Done");
        }
    });
    await $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/backend/edge/deleteOldAgent/',
        success: function() {
            console.log("Second Process Done");
        }
    });
}
```

actually, it's better done like

```
async function doAjax() {
    await $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/backend/edge/enableNewAgent/'
    });
    console.log("First Process Done");
    await $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/backend/edge/deleteOldAgent/'
    });
    console.log("Second Process Done");
}
```

Note, it HAS to be done inside a function (doesn't have to be a separate function like this, just put that there to enforce the idea ... `await` is only inside `async` function)

Comment: Sure, but if IE support is required this solution is smoked.

Comment: @EricHerlitz - have you heard of babel?

Comment: Yea, it's wild.

Answer (score 1):

Using `async: false` means that you never yield to the event loop, and the `console.log` lines get queued up (as do all other display updates).

My approach would be this:

```
function enableNewAgent() {
    return $.post('/backend/edge/enableNewAgent/',
        () => console.log('enableNewAgent Done')
    );
}

function deleteOldAgent() {
    return $.post('/backend/edge/deleteOldAgent/',
        () => console.log('deleteOldAgent Done')
    );
}

enableNewAgent().then(deleteOldAgent);
```

If you require further operations, add them to the `.then` chain:

```
enableNewAgent().then(deleteOldAgent).then(nextOperation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/backend/edge/enableNewAgent/',
  success: function() {
    console.log("First Process Done");
  }
}).then(function(){
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/backend/edge/deleteOldAgent/',
      success: function() {
        console.log("Second Process Done");
      }
    });
```

Comment: this probably won't fix the problem with the OP's `console.log` sequencing, but if you were to make it `async: true` instead (which is of course the right thing to do anyway) it would all work.

Comment: Still not wotking on >= 3rd ajax post :( stuck @Alnitak

Comment: @WilliamsPerdana there's a better than nested callbacks - see my answer.